# Determine in value change before updating in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on updating of table

> Table : User(id,name,Dob,createdDate,lastUpdatedDate)

I want to update lastUpdatedDate when there is change in Name column.

firstly I used update trigger but that is execute after updating of records

some helping link suggest me to use instead of Update trigger but if I use that one it will not update my records after trigger.

any solution?

Comment: If you use an instead of trigger, you have to code the update in the trigger. It runs *instead of* your update, not *before* it. Or, you could just change your update statement to also update the other column. How many different places in your code could possibly be updating the two mutable columns in this table?

Comment: what about accessing the table only through an SP that performs both the updates at the same time?

Comment: @AaronBertrand ok got it so solution is use update statement inside of instead trigger. thanks :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand but one question here that confuse me, if we  use update statement inside of instead of update trigger, that statement should also run another instead of update trigger because we are making update on same table?

Comment: No, the ideal solution is to run ONE update statement that updates the name and the updated date. If you need to use a trigger, it doesn't really matter if you use instead of or after, does it? (And don't worry, the update inside the instead of trigger doesn't fire the trigger again. Try it.)

Answer (score 0):

well I found suitable solution for this problem

in after update trigger there are two table sets one is Inserted and other one is Deleted.
so by getting name from both table sets we can campare there values. if there value is same we will not update lastUpdatedDate and if there is any difference in values then we will update lastUdpatedDate

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[User__Update]
       ON [dbo].[User]
AFTER Update
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;


        declare @AttributeValue varchar(max)

       declare @OldAttributeValue varchar(max)

       SELECT @AttributeValue = INSERTED.Name
       FROM INSERTED

       select @OldAttributeValue=Deleted.Name
        FROM Deleted

        if(@OldAttributeValue<>@AttributeValue)
        BEGIN
                 IF UPDATE(Name)  
                 BEGIN
                        update [User] set LastUpdatedDate=GetDate() where name =@AttributeValue
                 END
        END
END
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand I found this solution which is working fine